# Ipad 4 mini Date says 12,31,1969

Tags: terminal, application, stat

I used terminal code  `stat` in my iPad, and it came back as show below. Why does it say that date, how can I fix this? And is there other things I should check?

```
GFY iPad 2 $ stat
0 9870584235507384862 prw-rw---- 0 mobile mobile 0 0 "Dec 31 19:00:00 1969" "Dec 31 19:00:00 1969" "Dec 31 19:00:00 1969" "Dec 31 19:00:00 1969" 16384 0 0 (stdin)
GFY iPad 2 $
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are in a UTC-5 time zone, "Dec 31 19:00:00 1969" is time zero, the UNIX epoch.  The question then changes from "why this arbitrary time value" to "why zero?"

The four time values there are `atime` (last file access), `mtime` (last file modification), `ctime` (last inode change), and `btime` (inode birth time).  When no file is provided, `stat` gives information regarding whichever file is acting as its `stdin`.  On macOS, calling `stat` from a bare shell with no redirection, as you've done there, fills the first three of these with the current time but leaves the last uninitialized.

It would appear then that iPadOS behaves differently, leaving all fields unpopulated for the default standard input.

Comment: My timezone is Est standard..

Comment: EST is indeed UTC-5

Comment: So is this something I should worry???

Comment: why worry? there's no reason to believe from what you've posted here that your iPad actually thinks it's 1969